# Adding a data frame to the list in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

could someone explain why after running this code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2,2)), columns=['something1','something2'])
df_names=['something1','something2']
list1=[]
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0, len(df_names)):
        list2=[]
        for m in range(0,2):
            list2.append(m)
        df[df_names[j]]+=list2
    list1.append(df)
```

I get a data frame (like I wanted with headers: "something1", "something2", but the values ​​in this frame are added together)?

I mean, I wanted to get such a [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNZ89.png)

And instead of 1 I have 2 (i.e. sums up). It translates to the fact that in list I have two the same (bad) df, and I would like to have two df, but good (i.e. df added to the list after the **first** loop and df added to the list after the **second** loop).

I think at the end: `list.append(df)` works badly, but I don't know how to fix it..

Finally, i would like to receive it:
[df in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f2OH.png)
that is, a list and two df in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops... you were caught by the same object in multiple positions in a list problem.

A DataFrame is a mutable object. If you add the same dataframe in a list, you will only add multiple references to the real same object. So you add twice to the only dataframe, and have 2 references to it in your list.

How to fix?

A simple way it to create new objects in the loop:

```
list1=[]
for i in range(0,2):
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2,2)), columns=['something1','something2'])
    df_names=['something1','something2']
    for j in range(0, len(df_names)):
        list2=[]
        for m in range(0,2):
            list2.append(m)
        df[df_names[j]]+=list2
    list1.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because while the program is adding the elements inside the *for* loop, the original dataframe (df) is being manipulated.

During the first loop, it will create a dataframe with columns "something1" and "something2" and **0.0** and **1.0** as its values *(just like you wanted to)*

However, on the second loop, each column in the dataframe now has 0.0 and 1.0 as its value. And when we again add [0, 1] to it, **each values will now become 0.0 and 2.0**

Since the first dataframe inside **list1** has the same reference as the *original* **df**, it will also get affected and changed.

**TO SOLVE:**

- Use pd.DataFrame.copy() method to copy first the DataFrame (df) to avoid modifying it throughout inside the for loop.

  ```
    list1=[]

    for i in range(0,2):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        for j in range(0, len(df_names)):
            list2 = [] # [0, 1]
            for m in range(0,2):
                list2.append(m)
            df_copy[df_names[j]] += list2
        list1.append(df_copy)
  ```